# couldnot find other computer on locally connected area

Tags: ethernet

i am using ubuntu 14.04. now i work on a place where many computer are interconnected. sometimes i have to see other computer's file that are share. but i could not find any idea to see other file. other employee are using window7 and window8. and they too also counldnot find my PC name too. this gives me really a problem. 
i need to transfer file on my office using this network and sometime other employee has also need to copy or take file from my computer i.e hared file.
is there is not any such way to transfer file on ubuntu 14.04.
i can access there ip i.e localhost but could not find computer that are connected on ethernet.

Comment: ask the other users for their ip, then run `ping -c 3 ip_of_the_others` the others should do the same with your ip (get it using `ifconfig`).

Comment: You'll have to find out, if the other computers are there, to copy files you'll use `rsync` or `scp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can ping other people computers, you should next try to share a folder in your home folder (rigth-click on  it in the file manager). Ubuntu don't come with Windows share fully installed and you will be prompted to install it if needed. Reply yes, or, if you prefer, install the samba packages (client should be there, but you need the server too if you want Windows users to access your files).
Hope this helps...